# Dictionary TryGetValue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to preserve state in windows phone when user leaving my app.
How can I create a general method `TryGetValue` that gets value from dictionary?

My code so far:

```
    public class StatefulPhoneApplication : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        #region constructor
        public StatefulPhoneApplication()
        {
            IsNewPageInstance = true;
        }
        #endregion

        #region properties
        protected bool IsNewPageInstance { get; private set; }
        protected bool IsStatePreserved
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.State.ContainsKey("StatePreserved"))
                    return (bool)this.State["StatePreserved"];
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region preservation methods
        protected void PreserveControlState(Control control)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
                PreserveTextBoxState(control as TextBox);
            else
                PreserveCheckBoxState(control as CheckBox);

            this.State["StatePreserved"] = true;
        }

        protected void PreserveTextBoxState(TextBox textBox)
        {
            this.State[textBox.Name + ".Text"] = textBox.Text;
            this.State[textBox.Name + ".SelectionStart"] = textBox.SelectionStart;
            this.State[textBox.Name + ".SelectionLength"] = textBox.SelectionLength;
        }

        protected void PreserveCheckBoxState(CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            this.State[checkBox.Name + ".IsChecked"] = checkBox.IsChecked;
        }

        protected void PreserveFocusState(FrameworkElement parent)
        {
            Control focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as Control;

            if (focusedControl == null)
            {
                this.State["FocusedControlName"] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Control controlWithFocus = parent.FindName(focusedControl.Name) as Control;

                if (controlWithFocus == null)
                {
                    this.State["FocusedElementName"] = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.State["FocusedElementName"] = focusedControl.Name;
                }
            }   

        }
        #endregion

        #region restoration methods
        private void RestoreControlState(Control control)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
                RestoreTextBoxState(control as TextBox, string.Empty);
            else if (control is CheckBox)
                RestoreCheckBoxState(control as CheckBox, false);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I want to call just like this.

```
    private void RestoreTextBoxState(TextBox textBox, string defaultValue)
    {
        textBox.Text = TryGetValue<string>(textBox.Name + ".Text", defaultValue);
        textBox.SelectionStart = TryGetValue<int>(textBox.Name + ".SelectionStart", defaultValue);
        textBox.SelectionLength = TryGetValue<int>(textBox.Name + ".SelectionLength", defaultValue);
    }
```

I cannot find a good sample that works.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an extension method for IDictionary that I use:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> @this, TKey key, TValue @default = default(TValue)) {
    if (@this == null) return @default;

    TValue value;

    return @this.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : @default;
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    { 1, "one" },
    { 3, "three" }
};

string one = dict.GetValueOrDefault(1, "one");
string two = dict.GetValueOrDefault(2, "two");
string three = dict.GetValueOrDefault(3, "three");
```

After the above code, `one`, `two` and `three` will all be set to the correct string values, even though the dictionary has no entry for the key `2`

---

To achieve what you want without an extension method, you can just use the body of the method:

```
string temp;
string two = dict.TryGetValue(2, out temp) ? temp : "two";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have seen that code sample. But that code sample is static and if I remove **static** the I will get this error

"Extension method must be static"

Comment: You have to put the extension method in a static class of its own.

Comment: Extension methods are static by definition.

Comment: I am sorry for stupid and not understanding but "You have to put the extension method in a static class of its own." How do I do that?

Comment: @user3046164: You create a static class of any name and put this extension method.
Then you can call like how he shows in example. Simple..
:)

Comment: How about a `SetValueOrAdd()` extension method?

Comment: @ja72 that's the default behavior of the Dictionary's indexer (aka `dict["key"] = "value"`)

Comment: What and idiot I am. I have always checked if a value is contained before setting, or adding _for no reason apparently_.

Comment: What do you want updated? This code is just as valid now as it was when it was written.